# после checkout все изменения остаются как в старой ветке

Tags: git, git-branch

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой git, после checkout все изменения остаются как в ветке с которой перешел т.е. git status показывает то же самое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Это не проблема. Так и должно быть.

**Индекс один на весь репозиторий.** Для всех веток репозитория он один.

**А Git старается не терять изменений.** *Никогда.* И если при переходе между ветками изменения в индексе (внесённые `git add` или иными способами) конфликтуют с изменениями "между ветками", Git **откажется** делать `checkout`, сославшись на то, что ему придётся перезаписать часть изменений (он даже перечислит, какие именно); предлагая вместо этого их **закоммитить** или **положить в карман** (`stash`).

А если конфликта нет, он спокойно переключит рабочее дерево на другую ветку, никак не меняя состояние индекса. Что у вас и происходит.

Это особенно удобно, когда разработчик внёс изменения, а прямо перед коммитом (сделав все `git add`) понял, что внёс их не в ту ветку (скажем, случайно внёс в `master`, а хотел в `dev`). В простейшем случае дело ограничится двумя командами: `git checkout dev` и `git commit`.

Если всё же хотите сбросить индекс, **потеряв изменения в нём**, сделайте [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

Если хотите отложить изменения "на потом", сделайте [`git stash -k`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) (`k`: "Keep index"), а в нужном месте `git stash pop`.